# JavaEE+EJB InitialContext+ProgrammaticLogin for multiple connections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a gui (swing) client application and I want it to connect to different javaee servers (gf4) at the same time.

I am saying frankly I am newbie in javaee world and jaas so if I am wrong in something please correct me.

As I understood InitialContext is initialized via factory for every environment and the most important that it's initialized once and used again and again as client runs (factory keeps it). Thats why first initial context is created so long and next times it's created fast. I understood it after reading [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/naming/InitialContext.java).

**Question one**. If I am right is it possible to deinitialize certain context in order to initialize it again?

**Question two**. Is it normal practice to create initialcontext every time we want to lookup an ejb? I mean

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(Test.getContextEnv(0));
```

**Question three**. When we login via ProgrammaticLogin() to get access to ejb how can we match this ProgrammaticLogin() for certain initialcontext? I mean if we have two java ee servers how can we connect to each of them with different login/pass.

EDIT:
Question three is answered here - [How to remotely connect to multiple Glassfish 4+ instances simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234136/how-to-remotely-connect-to-multiple-glassfish-4-instances-simultaneously)

Comment: Hi P82. Did you found out how to connect to multiple gf4 servers simulteanously (e.g. Question three) ? ProgrammaticLogin has no direct link to the InitialContext - or I am wrong about this? How did you manage to connect to multiple instances simulteanously?

Comment: @salocinx To tell the truth I didn't find how to do that. Did you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question one. If I am right is it possible to deinitialize certain context in order to initialize it again?

A simpler approach is just create a new InitialContext instance with different environment properties.

> Question two. Is it normal practice to create initialcontext every time we want to lookup an ejb?

It is not necessary, you can use the same instance to lookup an ejb reference bound to the same context. 
Take in mind that the InitialContext instance is not synchronized, therefore, it will be a problem if several threads use the same instance concurrently.

> Question three. When we login via ProgrammaticLogin() to get access to ejb how can we match this ProgrammaticLogin() for certain initialcontext? I mean if we have two java ee servers how can we connect to each of them with different login/pass.

I'm not sure if I understand correctly this question, but if you have several InitialContext instances, 
each of them initialized with different environment properties, you could  programmatically decide which InitialContext (therefore, which server) is the right one to perform the login operation.

Comment: Hi Gabriel. But ProgrammaticLogin has no direct link to the InitialContext. How can I select which initial-context object is being used for ProgrammaticLogin.login(usr,pwd) ?

Comment: Hi @Hans Frankenstein, please make a new question providing more context and some details about your issue.